# django-rest-auth token authentication on client side

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have implemented Token Authentication in my api. When I send a POST request with user credentials, I get back the token. But I can't seem to figure how to implement client side logic to use this token. I mean do I store it somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Django Rest Framework Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

> For clients to authenticate, the token key should be included in the Authorization HTTP header. The key should be prefixed by the string literal "Token", with whitespace separating the two strings. For example:
>
> `Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b1`

So indeed, you need to store somewhere on the front-end.

You can read more about where is best place to store tokens [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80727/best-place-to-store-authentication-tokens-client-side).